# Getting Error - detector = cv2.AKAZE_create() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AKAZE_create' [7]+ Terminated: 15

Tags: opencv

I was able to run same Python script earlier not sure why I started getting this error from last 1 week. I re-installed opencv and opencv-contrib but still no luck.

Here is my code:

```
from future import print_functionimport
cv2 image = cv2.imread("IMG_3992.jpg") 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
cv2.imshow("Original", image) 
detector = cv2.AKAZE_create() (kps, descs) = detector.detectAndCompute(gray, None) 
print("keypoints: {}, descriptors: {}".format(len(kps), descs.shape))       
cv2.drawKeypoints(image, kps, image, (0, 255, 0))
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.imwrite('AKZ_3992.jpg',image) cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Can you please help me..Thanks a lot in advance..

Gags..

Comment: which OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.11
>>> cv2.__version__
'2.4.12'

Comment: That is why you got that error. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You said: `Python 2.7.11 >>> cv2.__version__ '2.4.12'`

So you are running OpenCV 2.4.12 but `cv2.AKAZE_create()` belongs to the set of features added to OpenCV 3.0 and later. It does not exist prior to this version.

The solution is hence to upgrade your OpenCV version.

Further reading: [*Fast Explicit Diffusion for Accelerated
Features in Nonlinear Scale Spaces*](http://isit.u-clermont1.fr/~ab/Publications/Alcantarilla_etal_BMVC13.pdf)